# background-color inherits from element where value is undefined

Tags: css

I have a DOM tree where a parent has a `background-color` property set. I want a child of that parent to inherit that `background-color`, but instead it inherits from its first parent. That first parent doesn't have a background color set, making the background of the child node transparent.

I know I could solve this by declaring the background-color explicitly in CSS, but I want the user to be able to set the `background-color` and `color` on the main parent and have it cascade properly. Plus this is pretty quirky behavior, so I was curious to see if anyone knew why this is the case, or how to solve it.

I put together [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leopld/5qfrc/) to illustrate the problem. I expected the span to have a red background, and the yellow div is there to illustrate that the span in fact *does not* have a red background.

Comment: so are you expecting the "span" should take red color?

Comment: Yep, that's right. I'll add that to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is absolutely normal behaviour. Parent of `span` isn't the `ul` element, it's rather it's "grandfather". So if `li` has not inherit something from `ul`, `span` won't inherit that as well.

Comment: Hmm maybe, but setting the color property on the main parent (ul) makes the color cascade through all the children. But I suppose this is because the default browser styling for every element goes like this?

    `color: inherit;`
    `background-color: transparent;`

Comment: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp) it doesn't make it cascade through all the children. They're just trnasparent.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `background-color` of your `ul > li` to `inherit` as well - that way `ul > li` inherits from `ul`, and `ul:span first-child` inherits from `ul > li`.

http://jsfiddle.net/5qfrc/2/

Comment: Yes, but what he needs to do is to set `span:first-child` background color to `inherit`. If you set this to `ul > li` you'll force whole `li` (each occurrence) to have same background as it's parent (what we want to avoid).